# How to integrate a splash screen activity and an app

Tags: java, android

I have made an app for my school project,i want to know how do i integrate two things in one?A splash screen with an app.

Answer (score 0):

The **correct** way to create a **splash screen** is doing that:

1) Create a **drawable** file like that named **splashscreen**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

    <item
        android:top="80dp"
        android:bottom="80dp">

        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

2)Add this **drawable** file as **background** of **main activity** like this and create a main style:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>

    </style>

<style name="Mainstyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

3) In you **main activity** add this line before **super.onCreate()** method:

```
setTheme(R.style.Mainstyle);
```

4)Add **theme** to the **manifest** file like that:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is the **correct** way to doing **recomended** by the **Google** in **android developers** site.